# AttributeError: type object 'SESConnection' has no attribute 'DefaultHost

Tags: python, django, email, amazon-web-services, boto

i am using CentOS and AWS ENV. prior it was wokring fine. after creation new instance and deploy same code.now i am getting following error:
AttributeError: type object 'SESConnection' has no attribute 'DefaultHost',

```
boto==2.24.0
    django-autofixture==0.2.5
    django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4
    django-extensions==0.6
    django-formwizard==1.0
    django-model-utils==1.0.0
    django-pylibmc-sasl==0.2.4
    django-ses==0.2
    django-uni-form==0.9.0

    python 2.6.6
    django 1.3.1



 mod_wsgi (pid=1137): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/stacks/django/myproject/config/apache/django.wsgi'., referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
 Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     response = self.get_response(request), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info()), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 209, in handle_uncaught_exception, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     'request':request, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1082, in error, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1173, in _log, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     self.handle(record), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1183, in handle, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     self.callHandlers(record), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1220, in callHandlers, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     hdlr.handle(record), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 679, in handle, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     self.emit(record), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 101, in emit, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     html_message=html_message), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 96, in mail_admins, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 251, in send, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self]), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 211, in get_connection, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     self.connection = get_connection(fail_silently=fail_silently), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 41, in get_connection, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     return klass(fail_silently=fail_silently, **kwds), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_ses/__init__.py", line 22, in __init__, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     SESConnection.DefaultHost), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
 AttributeError: type object 'SESConnection' has no attribute 'DefaultHost', referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
 mod_wsgi (pid=1132): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/stacks/django/myproject/config/apache/django.wsgi'., referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
 Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     response = self.get_response(request), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info()), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 209, in handle_uncaught_exception, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     'request':request, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1082, in error, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1173, in _log, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     self.handle(record), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1183, in handle, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     self.callHandlers(record), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1220, in callHandlers, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     hdlr.handle(record), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 679, in handle, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     self.emit(record), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 101, in emit, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     html_message=html_message), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 96, in mail_admins, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 251, in send, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self]), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 211, in get_connection, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     self.connection = get_connection(fail_silently=fail_silently), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 41, in get_connection, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     return klass(fail_silently=fail_silently, **kwds), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_ses/__init__.py", line 22, in __init__, referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
     SESConnection.DefaultHost), referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/
```

AttributeError: type object 'SESConnection' has no attribute 'DefaultHost', referer: http://ec2-24-20-18-576.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app_new/mail/

Comment: i did try with boto's different version( boto 2.0 )and django-ses 0.4.1 but not works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be configuration issue.another possibility your current instance don't have SES permission. i am not very much sure it would be correct answer. but you can try it. @Create new AMI image of working instance with SES feature. and launch new instance from that AMI no. and check it.

Another possibilities are:

MYSQL and APACHE server should be in running mode.

For MYSQL Server:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld status
```

if its not started then run

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

For Apache Server on Centos:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd status
```

if its not started then run

```
 /etc/init.d/httpd start
```